Get range that covers 90% of floats?
I've got an array that contains a large number (300,000) of floating-point values.  I'm feeding this array into a charting library (ScottPlot) which is mostly working fine.
The problem is, there could be "hiccups" in the data - by which I mean, I could have a dataset where most of the data is between -1,000 and +1,000 with an occasional spike (several values) < -100,000 or > +100,000.  When this happens, the auto-scaling auto-scales to the hiccups and the real data is hard to see.
Unfortunately, the datasets aren't consistent - so while dataset A might have good data between -100 and +100 with spikes of -10,000 and +10,000, dataset B might have good data between -10,000 and +10,000 with spikes of -1,000,000 and +1,0000,000 so I can't simply remove all data outside some fixed limits before calculating a min and max value for plot scaling.
Is there an algorithm that would let me calculate the smallest range (min and max values) that encompassed 90% of the data points, and I would then set the chart's y-axis to those min/max values?
EDIT
It has been suggested that my question is Calculating the 90th percentile in O(n) time but as I stated in my answer, that algorithm (among others) starts with sorting the data, and as I mentioned in my answer, sorting is highly inefficient for this problem.

The key word you're looking for here is "outlier" - I can't help with an algorithm, but adding that to your searches may help

Seems to be more of a statistical calculus (i.e. math) problem than a programming-related one.

^^ So, I'd look up some algorithms from there. If I had to shoot my shot without looking, I'd start by detecting outliers via a threshold computed from standard deviation * factor ... ? For a start ...

Yes, calculate the mean µ, and the standard deviation σ,  and set the range to [µ−σ, µ+σ], where you choose the constant  somewhere between 2 and 3. Just experiment with that constant.

You could calculate the 5 and the 95 percentile, and then subset your data between these values.  With Python and numpy, it would be something like perc5, perc95 = np.percentile(data, [5, 95]).  And selection = data[(data >= perc5) & (data <= perc95)].

@trincot Mean and standard deviation work for a normal distribution. But extreme outliers will throw off the variance like crazy.

300,000 isn't that big. You could go with a sort or a quickselect. But for additional speed, you can just randomly sample and then calculate from the sample.

This question is similar to: Calculating the 90th percentile in O(n) time.
The range that covers 90% of the values is bounded by the 5th and 95 percentile. There are many ways to calculate percentiles efficiently depending whether you want an exact or inexact value.

@PeteKirkham That doesn't seem right. If all outliers are high values and they're 10% of the data, wouldn't your way only remove half of them, and the other half would be kept and thus make the range far bigger than necessary?

@nocomment yes, if the data was not symmetric. The cases in the question are symmetric; if the question changes then it's not a dupe.

Your new edit part is wrong, the other question/answer is specifically about doing it in linear time, not with naive sorting.

You can try sliding window algorithm as no comment has described; here left and right are the sliding window borders:
private static (int leftIndex, int rightIndex) BestCoverage(double[] sortedArray, 
                                                            double minCoverage = 90.0) {
  var bestLeft = 0;
  var bestRight = sortedArray.Length - 1;

  for (int left = 0, right = 0; right < sortedArray.Length; ++right)
    for (; right - left + 1 >= sortedArray.Length * minCoverage / 100.0; ++left)
      if (sortedArray[right] - sortedArray[left] < sortedArray[bestRight] - sortedArray[bestLeft])
        (bestLeft, bestRight) = (left, right);

  return (bestLeft, bestRight);
}

Complexity: O(n) time, O(1) space.
Demo:
double[] array = { -100, 3, 5, 8, 9, 1000, 1e6, 1e9 };

var result = BestCoverage(array, 50);

Console.Write($"indexes: {result}");

Output:
indexes: (1, 4)

In order to have at least 50% coverage we should take items in [1..4] range which are {3, 5, 8, 9}.

You could slide a window over the sorted values, 90% of the elements wide, and find the smallest.
I don't know C#, but here's Python. I use 280,000 numbers in [-1000,1000] and 20,000 in [-1e6,1e6].
from random import randint, shuffle

a = (
  [randint(-1000, 1000) for _ in range(280_000)] +
  [randint(-1000000, 1000000) for _ in range(20_000)]
)
shuffle(a)

a.sort()
width = len(a) * 9 // 10
lo, hi = min(
    zip(a, a[width:]),
    key=lambda r: r[1]-r[0]
)

print(lo, hi)
print(sum(lo <= x <= hi for x in a))

Sample output, showing that the range [-989,939] contained 270,002 of the numbers (Attempt This Online!):
-989 939
270002


Here's what I came up with, and why.
First of all, there are a lot of interesting algorithms that one can use with sorted data, but it turns out I was off in my estimate of the size of my data.  Instead of 300,000 floats, it's between 7 and 10 million.  That means that the C# Array.Sort() function takes 1.4 to 1.7 seconds which is by itself much longer than any other complete algorithm, so that's not a good option.
Instead, I followed the suggestion from @trincot (calculate the mean µ, and the standard deviation σ, and set the range to [µ−σ, µ+σ]).  But my data sets are so varied there's no good fixed value for .  Instead I decided to calculate the best value for  in the current data set, but a binary search requires knowing the starting search interval.
In all my data sets, I never saw a useful value for  lower than 0.25 so I started there.  If N([µ−0.25σ, µ+0.25σ]) > 0.90 the algorithm stopped and used those values.
Otherwise, I searched for an upper limit on  like so:
float maxc;
int increment = 1;
for (; ; )
{
    float c = minc + increment;
    if (RangeIsWideEnough(allValues, ave, std, c))
    {
        maxc = c;
        break;
    }
    else
    {
        minc = c;
        increment++;
    }
}

Once I had minc and max, I did a simple binary search to narrow the range until (maxc - minc <= 0.25).  The entire process takes 200-600 msec.

Please, note that your approach works if distribution is close to normal; if you have some huge outliners, e.g. {1, 2, 1, 2, 3, ..., 1, 2, 1e100} you'll start from µ ~ 1e100 / 1e7 ~ 1e93 and the coverage will be far from optimal.

Random should be a lot faster. If you pick 10,000 random elements, and rank them, 99.9% of the time the bottom 5th percentile is between element 435 and 565. If it isn't, then 99.9% of the time it is within another 65 elements. With high likelihood that lets you narrow down each range to within 2% of your data with a single scan. Analyzing a much smaller dataset can be done in any way that you like.
